# How to merge two rxjs data and display in template?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have two observable data:

```
$selectedGroups: Observable<number[]>;
$groups: Observable<[{id: number, name: string}]>;
```

Inside template:

```
<app-registry-block *ngFor="let block of $groups | async">
  <div *ngIf="block.id in $selectedGroups">{{block.name}}</div>
</app-registry-block>
```

How to show component using `*ngIf` in case when there is a block id in `$selectedGroups`?.

Comment: `$selectedGroups | async`

Comment: Like this: `*ngIf="block.id in $selectedGroups | async"` ?

Comment: Is it okay practic?

Comment: What if mutate initial reponse `$groups:` and add property: `opend: boolean` then to use only `$groups` in temaplte?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter for selected groups in the component:

```js
$selectedGroupIds: Observable<number[]>;
$groups: Observable<{id: number, name: string}[]>;
// After first two are initialised
$selectedGroups = combineLatest([$selectedGroupIds, $groups])
  .pipe(
    map(([selectedGroupIds, groups]) => groups.filter(g => selectedGroupIds.includes(g.id)))
  );
```

Then in the template:

```html
<app-registry-block *ngFor="let block of $selectedGroups | async">
  <div>{{ block.name }}</div>
</app-registry-block>
```

---

P.S.: I would use an interface for the group type:

```js
export interface Group {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

Then the code becomes:

```js
$groups: Observable<Group[]>;
```

Comment: Is `[{id: number, name: string}]` really an intended type? Or do you mean `{id: number, name: string}[]`?

Comment: That means you have a type of `{id: number, name: string}[]`. `[{id: number, name: string}]` would have been an array of `{id: number, name: string}` with exactly one element.

Comment: If server returns an array of `{id: number, name: string}`, there is no need for conversion. Just pass the type generic in your http call: `this.httpClient.get<Group>(url)`.

Comment: In Redux effect I got dat from server `{Id: number, title: string, prop: true, items: []}`. On which step convert this data to `Group {id: number, name: string}`. Inside effect or in component or in reducer?